# Python's sympy solver returning bad roots on 4th degree equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, solver

I need to solve a 4th degree equation with python. For this I'm using the [*sympy*](http://www.sympy.org/) module.

When I run the script, *sympy* returns the 4 solutions of the equation as complex numbers (see output), while, in fact, all of them are real.

**What is making sympy return the wrong answer?**

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy import linalg as la
import sympy as sy

from matplotlib.pyplot import *

L = np.array([0,1,-20.0])
S = np.array([0,0,-10.0])

a = np.dot(S,S)
b = np.dot(S,L)
c = np.dot(L,L)

k0 = a - 1
k1 = 2*(a-b)
k2 = a + 2*b + c - 4*a*c
k3 = -4*(a*c - b**2)
k4 = 4*c*(a*c - b**2)

y = sy.Symbol('y')
r = sy.solvers.solve(k4*y**4 + k3*y**3 + k2*y**2 + k1*y + k0, y)

print r

y = np.linspace(-1.1, 1.1, 1000)
x = k4*y**4 + k3*y**3 + k2*y**2 + k1*y + k0
figure()
plot(y, x)
grid(True)
show()
```

Output:

```
[-0.994999960838935 + 1.66799419488535e-31*I,
 -0.0255580200028216 - 6.34301512012529e-30*I, 
  0.0243009597954184 + 6.32628752256216e-30*I,
  0.998750786632373 - 1.50071821925406e-31*I]
```

Plot (there are 4 zero-crossings):

[image]

Comment: Why are you solving a 4th order equation numerically when there is a known analytic formula?

Comment: Will generalize latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the result is actually real, up to numerical precision. `e-30` is really a small number. The solutions reported are also consistent with the plot, so nothing to worry about.

Comment: Isn't the `_.__*I` part the imaginary component? I see that this is very small and non significant, but it shouldn't be there in first place, and it complicates everything as I need to check for real/complex roots (which sometimes they legitimately appear).

Comment: Yes it is, and it is of the order `10^{-30}`. You can use `numpy` `isclose()`  function to decide whether the imaginary part can be neglected. From a numerical solver, you would expect some error. In the general case the returned value of this function is complex, so the solver should be 'analytically' smart to understand whether what it is looking at is a rounding error or a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Real values can also be obtained directly from `nroots`:

```
>>> eq=k4*y**4 + k3*y**3 + k2*y**2 + k1*y + k0
>>> eq
160400.0*y**4 - 400.0*y**3 - 159499.0*y**2 - 200.0*y + 99.0
>>> nroots(eq)
[-0.994999960838935, -0.0255580200028216, 0.0243009597954184, 0.998750786632373]
```